# Do web hosting companies cache pages?

Tags: language-agnostic

Do web hosts usually cache your content? You know like caching proxies.

I was just wondering is it good practise to always control the cache properly? I have seen alot of sites without cache control in the head section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Web Hosts will generally not cache anything.

One because it's a lot of work and uses their processing power.

Secondly because it could reduce bandwidth use, and they would prefer you go over your bandwidth so they can charge you more.  (Even most unlimited bandwidth packages have a limit, read the Terms)

Thirdly if they control the caching process and you don't want your website cached it would be a lot of work to go through the effort of turning it off for certain websites.

So yes, it would be a good practice to control your cache properly.

Answer (score 0):

Most of hosts do not cache anything. Though it would be really wise to set proper cache-control headers anyway< because there still may be some proxies between your server and browsers.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the 2nd part of your question, you really need cache-headers if you:

- don't want your pages to be cached at all
- want to make sure your pages (and/or images, js, css, ...) will be cached

if you don't specify caching-directives in your response headers, proxies and browsers can -and will- decide whether or not to cache on their own.

it is good practice to try to avoid being at the mercy of some unknown piece of code ;-)